# pythonで複数のtxtファイルを一度に読み込みたい

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Jupyterで複数のtxtファイルを一度に読み込むにはどうすればいいのでしょうか.
例えば，fileというディレクトリに格納された、`data1.txt〜data100.txt` というファイルを読み込んで、それぞれを変数 `data1〜data100`としたい時、

```
f1=open('file/data1.txt', 'r','utf-8')
data1=f1.read()
f1.close()
```

という動作を繰り返させたいのですが、皆様でしたらどうされるでしょうか。
初歩的な質問で大変恐縮ですが、ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ファイル名を `data1.txt` から `data100.txt` まで繰り返すには、[`str.format()`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) 関数が使えます。たとえば変数 `i` が `1` から `100` まで繰り返すとき、`'data{}.txt'.format(i)` と書くと `data1.txt` から `data100.txt` までを繰り返せます。

また、読み込んだ 100 個のファイルデータをそれぞれ格納するには、長さが 100 のリストを作る方が良いでしょう。`data1` から `data100` までの 100 個の変数を作るのではなく、`data` という変数を作り `data[0]` から `data[99]` までで参照できるようにしよう、ということです。

これらを踏まえ、たとえば下のように書けます。

```
data = [None] * 100
for i in range(100):
    f = open('file/data{}.txt'.format(i + 1), mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
    data[i] = f.read()
    f.close()
```

もっと言うと、これだと `read()` している間にエラーが起こると `close()` されないかもしれないため、次のように `with` を使って書き直した方が良いです。このことは Python 3 の[チュートリアルに書かれています](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)。

```
data = [None] * 100
for i in range(100):
    with open('file/data{}.txt'.format(i + 1), mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data[i] = f.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

連続してデータを作成するような処理を書くならイテレータ・ジェネレータは覚えておいたほうがお得です。

```
from pathlib import Path

def readfiles():
    for i in range(1, 101):
        yield Path('file/data{}.txt'.format(i)).read_text()

data = list(readfiles())
```

読み込み処理は中でやってるのは `open()` して `read()` してるのと同じです。
読み込んだデータを直接変更しないなら `list()` ではなく `tuple()` で。